# HttpClient.PostAsync crash app. How to catch the Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to test this HttpRequest:

```
 public void TestX(string baseUrl)
        {
            StringContent httpContentDistanza = new StringContent(GlobalVariables.JsonDistanza);
            using HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)
            };

            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;

            try
            {
                responseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync("/xxx/xx/xxx", httpContentDistanza).Result;
              // can't reach the code below
                if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string strContext = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    var risultato = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Distanza1>(strContext);

                    GlobalVariables.DblAijCrnPsz = risultato.data.processDataIn.valore;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (responseMessage == null)
                {
                    responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
                }
                responseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                responseMessage.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("RestHttpClient.SendRequest failed: {0}", ex);
            
            }
        }
```

The problem is that the URI is not reachable, and I was expecting that its gonna throw some Exception, but it did not.

In case where URI is not reachable I need some how to catch that Exception.

I'm using `BackgroundWorker` to run `TestX()`:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
            bgWorker.DoWork += ResetAll;

        }

        private void ResetAll(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
           var x = gestLink.TestX(GlobalVariables.BaseUrl).ToString();
           //it also does't reach the code below

               ....
        }
```

---

**Update**

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. I still can't catch the exception :

```
     public async Task TestX(string baseUrl)
            {
              StringContent httpContentDistanza = new  StringContent(GlobalVariables.JsonDistanza);

              using HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient
               {
                  BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)
               };
        
               HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
             
                try
                {
                    responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("/xxx/xxx/xx", httpContentDistanza);
    
                    if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string strContext = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
                     var risultato = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Distanza1>(strContext);

                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    var error = ex.Message;
                }
```

It crash here  `responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("/xxx/xx/xxx", httpContentDistanza);` but stops in `ResetAll()` and  var x = [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EBl9.png).

---

I have seen and read similar problems ([Debugger stops after async HttpClient.GetAsync()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281073/debugger-stops-after-async-httpclient-getasync-call-in-visual-studio)  and [HttpClient.PostAsync and await crashing app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133061/c-sharp-httpclient-postasync-and-await-crashing-app)) before, but no solutions have helped me.
Any suggestions how to catch the exception?

Comment: Maybe check the Result you get from POST? If its an unknown subsite you'll get 404 HttpCode. Maybe that helps

Comment: How? After `ponseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync("/xxx/xx/xxx", httpContentDistanza).Result;` it crash and doesn't reach any line of code

Comment: You have and asynchronous method called in an synchronous context. So basically PostAsync does not block and runs on another thread context.

Comment: What you need to do is a) Put the Async call in an async method and decorate the call with an await or b) use a synchronous overload for HttpClient.Post

Comment: @mjwills <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework> Btw, the call and the respons must be instant, that's why I don't want to use Async and Await. I should show the response in UI for 50 milliseconds max .

Comment: `Btw, the call and the respons must be instant, that's why I don't want to use Async and Await.` What makes you think async / await makes it less instant? You may as well give async / await a try - it couldn't be any _slower_ than what you have now. ;)

Comment: Does `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` work rather than `.Result` (although, again, async await would be better).

Comment: So it should be like this : `responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("/iolink/sickv1/readDevice", httpContentDistanza);` ?

Comment: Yes I try it :  `public async void TestX(string baseUrl){...responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("/iolink/sickv1/readDevice", httpContentDistanza);.....}` Its the same. It crash on  `responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("/iolink/sickv1/readDevice", httpContentDistanza)`

Comment: Try putting .ConfigureAwait(false) after the call to the request, this could be a problem with sincronization context depending of .net version you are using

Comment: @MestreDosMagros  `responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("/iolink/sickv1/readDevice", httpContentDistanza).ConfigureAwait(false);`nothing changed. I try that before

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void

Answer (score 3):

You should change this:

```
public void TestX(string baseUrl)
```

to

```
public async Task TestX(string baseUrl)
```

and this

```
responseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync("/xxx/xx/xxx",httpContentDistanza).Result;
```

to

```
responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("/xxx/xx/xxx", httpContentDistanza);
```

Then you can handle Exceptions.

Comment: i did that before, in the beginning. Its the same. And I just update my question